# PHP Find experience of next level

Tags: php, math

Let's say I have this simple function

```
<?php

function levels($theExp) {

          if ($theExp < 52) { $theLevel = 2;}
          else if ($theExp < 110) { $theLevel = 3;}
          else if ($theExp < 175) { $theLevel = 4;}
          else if ($theExp < 246) { $theLevel = 5;}
          else if ($theExp < 325) { $theLevel = 6;}
          else if ($theExp < 413) { $theLevel = 7;}
          else if ($theExp < 510) { $theLevel = 8;}
          else if ($theExp < 616) { $theLevel = 9;}
          else if ($theExp < 734) { $theLevel = 10;}
          else if ($theExp < 865) { $theLevel = 11;}
          else if ($theExp < 1008) { $theLevel = 12;}
          else if ($theExp < 1167) { $theLevel = 13;}
          else if ($theExp < 1342) { $theLevel = 14;}
          else if ($theExp < 1536) { $theLevel = 15;}
          else if ($theExp < 1749) { $theLevel = 16;}
          else if ($theExp < 1985) { $theLevel = 17;}
          else if ($theExp < 2245) { $theLevel = 18;}
          else if ($theExp < 2531) { $theLevel = 19;}
          else if ($theExp < 2848) { $theLevel = 20;}
          else if ($theExp < 3197) { $theLevel = 21;}
          else if ($theExp < 3582) { $theLevel = 22;}
          else if ($theExp < 4007) { $theLevel = 23;}
          else if ($theExp < 4476) { $theLevel = 24;}
          else if ($theExp < 4993) { $theLevel = 25;}
          else if ($theExp < 5564) { $theLevel = 26;}
          else if ($theExp < 6193) { $theLevel = 27;}
          else if ($theExp < 6888) { $theLevel = 28;}
          else if ($theExp < 7655) { $theLevel = 29;}
          else if ($theExp < 8502) { $theLevel = 30;}
          else if ($theExp < 9435) { $theLevel = 31;}
          else if ($theExp < 10466) { $theLevel = 32;}
          else if ($theExp < 11603) { $theLevel = 33;}
          else if ($theExp < 12858) { $theLevel = 34;}
          else if ($theExp < 14243) { $theLevel = 35;}
          else if ($theExp < 15772) { $theLevel = 36;}
          else if ($theExp < 17459) { $theLevel = 37;}
          else if ($theExp < 19321) { $theLevel = 38;}
          else if ($theExp < 21376) { $theLevel = 39;}
          else if ($theExp < 23644) { $theLevel = 40;}
          else if ($theExp < 26148) { $theLevel = 41;}
          else if ($theExp < 28912) { $theLevel = 42;}
          else if ($theExp < 31962) { $theLevel = 43;}
          else if ($theExp < 35329) { $theLevel = 44;}
          else if ($theExp < 39046) { $theLevel = 45;}
          else if ($theExp < 43149) { $theLevel = 46;}
          else if ($theExp < 47677) { $theLevel = 47;}
          else if ($theExp < 52677) { $theLevel = 48;}
          else if ($theExp < 58195) { $theLevel = 49;}
          else if ($theExp < 64288) { $theLevel = 50;}
          else if ($theExp < 71013) { $theLevel = 51;}
          else if ($theExp < 78437) { $theLevel = 52;}
          else if ($theExp < 86633) { $theLevel = 53;}
          else if ($theExp < 95681) { $theLevel = 54;}
          else if ($theExp < 105670) { $theLevel = 55;}
          else if ($theExp < 116697) { $theLevel = 56;}
          else if ($theExp < 128871) { $theLevel = 57;}
          else if ($theExp < 142311) { $theLevel = 58;}
          else if ($theExp < 157148) { $theLevel = 59;}
          else if ($theExp < 173529) { $theLevel = 60;}
          else if ($theExp < 191614) { $theLevel = 61;}
          else if ($theExp < 211579) { $theLevel = 62;}
          else if ($theExp < 233622) { $theLevel = 63;}
          else if ($theExp < 257958) { $theLevel = 64;}
          else if ($theExp < 284825) { $theLevel = 65;}
          else if ($theExp < 314487) { $theLevel = 66;}
          else if ($theExp < 347236) { $theLevel = 67;}
          else if ($theExp < 383392) { $theLevel = 68;}
          else if ($theExp < 423310) { $theLevel = 69;}
          else if ($theExp < 467382) { $theLevel = 70;}
          else if ($theExp < 516039) { $theLevel = 71;}
          else if ($theExp < 569760) { $theLevel = 72;}
          else if ($theExp < 629070) { $theLevel = 73;}
          else if ($theExp < 694553) { $theLevel = 74;}
          else if ($theExp < 766850) { $theLevel = 75;}
          else if ($theExp < 846671) { $theLevel = 76;}
          else if ($theExp < 934799) { $theLevel = 77;}
          else if ($theExp < 1032098) { $theLevel = 78;}
          else if ($theExp < 1139523) { $theLevel = 79;}
          else if ($theExp < 1258129) { $theLevel = 80;}
          else if ($theExp < 1389078) { $theLevel = 81;}
          else if ($theExp < 1533655) { $theLevel = 82;}
          else if ($theExp < 1693280) { $theLevel = 83;}
          else if ($theExp < 1869518) { $theLevel = 84;}
          else if ($theExp < 2064099) { $theLevel = 85;}
          else if ($theExp < 2278932) { $theLevel = 86;}
          else if ($theExp < 2516125) { $theLevel = 87;}
          else if ($theExp < 2778005) { $theLevel = 88;}
          else if ($theExp < 3067142) { $theLevel = 89;}
          else if ($theExp < 3386373) { $theLevel = 90;}
          else if ($theExp < 3738830) { $theLevel = 91;}
          else if ($theExp < 4127973) { $theLevel = 92;}
          else if ($theExp < 4557619) { $theLevel = 93;}
          else if ($theExp < 5031985) { $theLevel = 94;}
          else if ($theExp < 5555725) { $theLevel = 95;}
          else if ($theExp < 6133979) { $theLevel = 96;}
          else if ($theExp < 6772421) { $theLevel = 97;}
          else if ($theExp < 7477315) { $theLevel = 98;}
          elseif ($theExp < 8255580) { $theLevel = 99;}

          return $theLevel;

      }

      ?>
```

You put in your EXP and it will give you your LEVEL. These two nubmers are pulled from a MySQL database...

So, let's say we have `$level` and `$exp`.

How would I find the expereince left to get to the next level given my `$level` is `1` and `$exp` is `0`?

Comment: At level 4 shouldn`t it be 176?

Answer (score 1):

You should use loop instead of writing that many conditions, or even a switch sentence. Anyway, in order to find the exp left you have to calculate the difference between the upcoming level exp and the current exp:

```
echo 'Remaining exp to level 3:' , 110 - $theExp;
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you should make an array for both `exp` and `level`, it will be easier for you to manipulate, eg:

```
function levels($theExp, $next = null) {
    $levels = array(
            2 => 52,
            3 => 110,
            4 => 175
           );
    foreach($levels as $level => $exp){
        if($exp > $theExp){
            return ($exp-$theExp);
        }
    }
    return 'MAX LEVEL';
}
$thisLevel = levels(63); // 47
```

Comment: make an array for both? What do you mean?

Comment: insert the level and exp in same array, like the function I've made.

Answer (score 1):

Make a levels array with experience limits in it, i.e.

```
$levels = array(
  1 => 0,
  2 => 52,
  3 => 110,
  ...
);
```

Then, when you know your current exp, you can walk through levels array

```
function getNextLevel(&$levels,$experience) {
    $levelscount = count(array_keys($levels));
    $currentlevel = 0;
    for ($a = 1; $a <= $levelscount; $a++) {
        if ($levels[$a] > $experience) {
            $for_next_level = $levels[$a]-$experience;
            return array('level'=>$a-1, 'for_next_level'=>$for_next_level);
        } else if ($levels[$a] == $experience) {
            $for_next_level = $levels[$a+1]-$experience;
            return array('level'=>$a, 'for_next_level'=>$for_next_level);   
        }
    }
    return array('level'=>$levelscount, 'for_next_level'=>null); // if maxed the experience
}


getNextLevel($levels,50); // Array ( [level] => 1 [for_next_level] => 2 )
getNextLevel($levels,52); // Array ( [level] => 2 [for_next_level] => 58 )
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way of doing this is to write a mathematical function; level as function of experience. If you plot your level approximation, you get a graph that looks like this:

[image]

This can be approximated very accurately (correlation error is 0.99968917) with this expression:

[image]

```
function levels($exp) {
    if( $exp < 52 ) return( 2 );
    if( $exp > 8255580 ) return( 99 );

    $exp2 = pow($exp, 2);
    $exp3 = pow($exp, 3);
    $exp4 = pow($exp, 4);

    $part_a = 
        (-7083090.21554248 * $exp) -
        (2660.03667387467 * $exp2) -
        (0.00893506217859665 * $exp3);

    $part_b =
        (9.21358754706152e-13*$exp4) -
        246214420.822165 -
        (511314.94011467 * $exp) -
        (52.7886099211375 * $exp2) -
        (9.50051322037161e-5*$exp3);

    return( intval($part_a / $part_b) );
}
```

This is obviously a rough estimate of the equation, but it works decently well to fit without spaghetti code.  It passes your binary clip test within 100% tolerance only about 40/96 times, but when it's off, it's off by a hairlength. See this graph for a comparison of fit: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UUqOe.png

**Edit:** to answer your original question, "experience left to get to the next level" is now calculated by math.  Since this approach is math based, the equation is reversible, so when you solve for experience, you can write an inverse function (note this is a rough estimate also, and errs in lower bounds, so you'll need to refine it for exp-levels < 2500):

```
function experience( $level ) {
    if( $level < 20 ) {
        return( intval(
            52.4648221531097*$level + 
            0.441063182292944*pow($level,3) + 
            0.00123813768395424*pow($level,5) - 
            57.3134003957015 - 
            0.0279703679732544*pow($level,4) - 
            1.81609930709489e-5*pow($level,6)
        ) );
    }

    return( intval(
        2520.69249517965 + 
        (5.46368150243298e-6*pow($level,6)) + 
        (1.30082368317228e-13*pow($level,10)) - 
        (9.417224294e-10*pow($level,8))
    ));
}
```

So, to compute experience needed for next level by this approach: `$needed = experience($current_level + 1) - experience($current_level);`